# Where is an appropriate place to put Application wide date formatting in iOS?

Tags: ios, design-patterns

In a typical iOS application, where should one put application wide objects? I'd like to centralized my Date formatting code and I would be interested in hearing suggestions on best practices for doing so.

For example, I have the following code to do date formatting:

```
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSString *usFormatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"EEE, MMM d YYY" options:0 locale:usLocale];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = usFormatString;

((UILabel *)[selectedCell.contentView viewWithTag:1]).text = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

I'd like to keep the formatting code as DRY as possible.

**EDIT**: This turned out to be a multipart answer and I took the approach of using a combination of a Singleton and creating a Category for NSString. I upvoted most of you, but I accepted @Jack_Lawrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using Objective-C categories for that sort of stuff. Categories are good for extending the abilities of existing objects, especially objects from frameworks that you don't have control over. Make sure to prefix method names so you don't conflict with current/future methods Apple may implement.

In this specific case, I would create a category on NSDate called NSDate+DateFormatting and implement a method that returns an NSString from the date receiver:

```
- (NSString *)JL_stringByFormattingDate
{
    NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    NSString *usFormatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"EEE, MMM d YYY" options:0 locale:usLocale];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = usFormatString;

    return [formatter stringFromDate:self.date];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For things like this I would always suggest using singletons rather than putting functions in the app delegate.

The below article has a really good overview of how to use singletons , and their advantages.

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html

Answer (score 1):

Usually "application wide" objects can be referenced via a property that you add to your application's delegate.

So create a `NSDateFormatter` and assign it to a property that you can reference from your delegate via something like:

```
NSDateFormatter * myAppDateFormatter = nil;
MyFineAppDelegate * myAppDelegate = (MyFineAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if(myAppDelegate)
{
     myAppDateFormatter = myAppDelegate.dateFormatter;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Just before you answered, I created a Singleton "DateUtilies" class that seems to work fine. Would you say that your solution is more appropriate or inline with iOS best practices??

Comment: I was giving you the easiest answer (which hopefully will help other people get onto the right track if they look up your question down the road). The "Best Practice" answer here is actually very subjective and depends on your application implementation, your overall MVC architecture, your style, etc.

Comment: You should not arbitrarily add stuff to the AppDelegate. This is the most prevalent cause of cause of poor software design in iOS projects. Keep doing this, your will end up with a monolithic class that has no cohesion.

Comment: Hello @lorean and thanks for the downvote.  Like I said before, I was trying to give the original poster a quick route to success (since that is what most newbies care most about).  And yes, a better solution would be to come up with something more elegant and Object Oriented (a singleton, a category extension, whatever), which is what I do in my own code and certainly you would as well.

Answer (score 1):

Singleton classes are a possible solution. Basically, wherever you call the object from, it will return the same instance. See [here](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/xcode-tip-singleton-class-template/) for some more info and a how to.